# Reading from file in R when I have a part of its name

Tags: r

How can I read from a file in R when I have only a part of its name including starting or ending characters?

Thanks

Comment: How about using `list.files()` to get a list of all the files in the working directory, then see which one matches your criteria, then read it. You've given so few details it's hard to be more specific.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `list.files`, which has a `pattern` argument, to try to match as close as you can.

```
writeLines(c('hello', 'world'), '~/tmp/example_file_abc')
filename <- list.files(path = '~/tmp', pattern = 'file_abc$', full.names = TRUE)[1]
readLines(filename)
# [1] "hello" "world"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also `Sys.glob` which will expand patterns using stars and question marks according to `glob` syntax.

Here it is wrapped in a function to match filenames of the form `"first*last"` where `"*"` is anything. If you really have stars or other special chars in your filename... then you need to do a bit more.. Anyway:

```
> match_first_last = function(first="", last="", dir=".")
   {Sys.glob(
      file.path(dir,paste(first,"*",last,sep=""))
      )
    }


# matches "*" and so everything:
> match_first_last()
[1] "./bar.X" "./foo.c" "./foo.R"

# match things starting `foo`    
> match_first_last("foo")
[1] "./foo.c" "./foo.R"

# match things ending `o.c`
> match_first_last(last="o.c")
[1] "./foo.c"

# match start with f, end in R
> match_first_last("f","R")
[1] "./foo.R"
```